# Apache don't work on /media

Tags: permissions, apache2, search

My Apache is configured to listen 127.0.0.1.
But, only 127.0.1.1 works with Apache Page, and "localhost" works too.
Searching on logs files, I found it:

```
AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/xxxxxx/yyyyyy') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

I need use Apache on media folder, but I not want to give to Apache execution permissions on parents folders. Like "`chmod -R +x /media/`". I believe that if unsecured.
On this link: https://www.andrewklau.com/permission-denied-because-search-permissions-are-missing-on-a-component-of-the-path/
The user speak about "search feature" of Apache, on parents directory.
But I can not disable it. I'm try "-Indexes" or "+Indexes" on "000-default.conf", on my virtual host that use this path: '/media/xxxxxx/yyyyyy'. But nothing works.

Can you help-me?

Comment: You should change the permission of the `/media` directory to 755. The directories should be executable by others.

Comment: @RoseHosting, I believe that if unsecured. Or not?

Comment: I not only had to change `/media` to 755 but also `/media/pi` to get access to my external drive mounted in `/media/pi/nas`

Comment: Yes @LPrc you are correct... Needs to be recursively... And RoseHosting didn't remember this.